# How to filter array in jsonpath on a value at the top level?

Tags: json, jsonpath

Case in point - I want to get the default k8s namespace using the `kubectl config view` command using jsonpath.

Here is what I have so far:

```
C:\> kubectl config current-context
app508-mk-aks
C:\> kubectl config view -o jsonpath="{.contexts[?(@.name=='app508-mk-aks')].context.namespace}"
default
C:\> kubectl config view -o jsonpath="{.current-context}"
app508-mk-aks
C:\>
```

According to https://support.smartbear.com/alertsite/docs/monitors/api/endpoint/jsonpath.html I should be able to use `$`:

```
C:\> kubectl config view -o jsonpath='{.contexts[?(@.name==$.current-context)].context.namespace}'
C:\>
```

But it returns nothing!

What am I missing?